# Is it possible to use same indexer for Sites and DOCS search

Tags: sites-9, tridion-docs, elasticsearch

We are planning to implement Search functionality for our DX customer using Elastic Search. I doubt if we can use the same indexer for both Tridion Sites and Docs.

Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, You can use the same elastic instance to have two different indexes for docs and sites.

OOTB - IQ-Index and IQ-Query services only supported for Docs.

**Note:** IQ services won’t work with the SI4T index for sites.

I hope it helps.

Comment: But if we can index Docs content using the IQ Indexer, and we can index the Sites content using SI4T, and it is all indexed into the same Elasticsearch instance, then couldn't we in theory just switch the IQ Indexer to have an index that matches the Sites index - and then everything from both Sites and Docs would be under the same index? This would not require the IQ services to interact with SI4t.